# Unsupervised Outlier detection

Tags: python-3.x, cluster-analysis, curve-fitting, outliers, lmfit

I have 6 points in each row and have around 20k such rows. Each of these row points are actually points on a curve, the nature of curve of each of the rows is same (say a sigmoidal curve or straight line, etc). These 6 points may have different x-values in each row.I also know a point (a,b) for each row which that curve should pass through. How should I go about in finding the rows which may be anomalous or show an unexpected behaviour than other rows? I was thinking of curve fitting but then I only have 6 points for each curve, all I know is that majority of the rows have same nature of curve, so I can perhaps make a general curve for all the rows and have a distance threshold for outlier detection.

Comment: Take twice the standard deviation. Every non outlier shall be between mean  minus twice std dev and mean plus twice std dev. (up to 3x might work better)

Comment: Mean of y for each value of x? But I may have only one value of y for each value of x, I don't understand

Comment: Try using the mean of all y values and its standard deviation. Then evaluate, for every x, if y falls between the range. See if this works. Let me know

Comment: An outlier should be taken as more like 5*sigma away from the mean: 2*sigma is definitely not an outlier!  I'm not sure I understand your data structure.  Does each column correspond to a single X value?  Anyway, posting a small example of what you are trying to do would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you just treat the 6 points as a 12 dimensional vector and run any of the usual outlier detection methods such as LOF and LoOP?

It's trivial to see the relationship between Euclidean distance on the 12 dimensional vector, and the 6 Euclidean distances of the 6 points each. So this will compare the similarities of these curves.

You can of course also define a complex distance function for LOF.